# How do I get person name based on Timestampcreate element date and time value

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Using my xml document, I would like to display the **Respondent's** name in my output.

**Here is the condition**
When the current status `<TimestampCreate>`element has a date and time before noon 03/24/2016, display the formattedname from `Party/PartyName` element.

Otherwise when current status `<TimestampCreate>`has a date after noon 03/24/2016, display formattedname from `CaseParty/CasePartyName` element.

How do I do this?

**My xml document**

```
<Integration>
    <Case>
        <CaseParty ID="17154970" InternalCasePartyID="1636956553" InternalPartyID="1615052853">
            <Connection Word="RSP" BaseConnection="DF" ID="39228182" InternalCasePartyConnectionID="1638740325">
                <Description>Respondent</Description>
                <TimestampCreate>4/27/2016 9:25:08 AM</TimestampCreate>
                <DateAdded>04/27/2016</DateAdded>
            </Connection>
            <CasePartyName Current="true" ID="10737806" InternalNameID="1615969730">
                <FormattedName>Tree, Walnut</FormattedName>
            </CasePartyName>
            <TimestampCreate>4/27/2016 9:25:08 AM</TimestampCreate>
        </CaseParty>
        <ProtectionOrders>
            <ProtectionOrder Op="E" InternalProtectionOrderID="2408">
                <Statuses>
                    <Status Op="A">
                        <Current>true</Current>
                        <Active>Yes</Active>
                        <Date Op="A">04/27/2016</Date>
                        <TimestampCreate Op="A">04/27/2016 12:01:58:963</TimestampCreate>
                    </Status>
                </Statuses>
            </ProtectionOrder>
        </ProtectionOrders>
    </Case>
    <Party ID="17154970" InternalPartyID="1615052853">
        <PartyName ID="10737806" Current="true" InternalNameID="1615969730">
            <FormattedName>Nelson, Plince</FormattedName>
    </Party>
</Integration>
```

**My XSLT code**

```
<xsl:for-each select="CasePartyName[@Current='true']">
    <xsl:value-of select="FormattedName"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear - and your input is not well-formed.

In general, XSLT 1.0 has no concept of dates or times, and the only size comparison it can do is numerical. That means you must convert your timestamps to numbers in such way that a later timestamp will produce a larger number.

For example, given the following input:

**XML**

```
<root>
   <node>
        <TimestampCreate>3/23/2016 9:25:08 AM</TimestampCreate>
   </node>
   <node>
        <TimestampCreate>3/24/2016 9:25:08 AM</TimestampCreate>
   </node>
   <node>
        <TimestampCreate>3/24/2016 9:25:08 PM</TimestampCreate>
   </node>
   <node>
        <TimestampCreate>3/25/2016 9:25:08 AM</TimestampCreate>
   </node>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="node">
            <item>
                <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before(TimestampCreate, ' ')" />
                <xsl:variable name="time" select="substring-before(substring-after(TimestampCreate, ' '), ' ')" />
                <xsl:variable name="pm" select="contains(TimestampCreate,'p') or contains(TimestampCreate,'P')"/>

                <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-after(substring-after($date, '/'), '/')" />
                <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before($date, '/')" />
                <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-before(substring-after($date, '/'), '/')" />

                <xsl:variable name="hour12" select="substring-before($time, ':')" />
                <xsl:variable name="minute" select="substring-before(substring-after($time, ':'), ':')" />
                <xsl:variable name="second" select="substring-after(substring-after($time, ':'), ':')" />

                <xsl:variable name="hour" select="$hour12 mod 12 + 12*$pm"/>

                <xsl:variable name="timestamp-num" select="$second + 100 * $minute + 10000 * $hour + 1000000 * $day + 100000000 * $month + 10000000000 * $year"/>

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$timestamp-num &lt; 20160324120000">
                        <!-- RESULT WHEN BEFORE -->
                        <xsl:text>BEFORE</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <!-- RESULT WHEN AFTER -->
                        <xsl:text>AFTER</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <item>BEFORE</item>
   <item>BEFORE</item>
   <item>AFTER</item>
   <item>AFTER</item>
</output>
```